# Symfony doesn't find pdo_sqlsrv driver

Tags: symfony, doctrine, server, driver, sqlsrv

I have one problem with Doctrine (or with my server configuration, I don't know where is the problem) in my Symfony2 web. I have been looking for an answer since several days but I haven't found it yet.

I need to connect my symfony web to a remote Microsoft SQL database through Doctrine. For this reason, I have added the "database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv" param in app/config/parameters.yml, but when I try to execute (in my Mac) a command like:

> php bin/console doctrine:database:create

or

> php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product

I get the following error:
[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] could not find driver
[PDOException] could not find driver

I have checked the phpinfo and the driver doesn't appear (only mysql, sqlite). I don't know if it's possible to add MSSQL, because in Microsoft SQL Server Functions ([PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)) appears that it needs to be running on a Windows.

Is not possible to access a mssql database without Windows? (If yes, how can I do it).

Would I need a Windows hosting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have FreeTDS installed?

Comment: No, I don't. I will take a look. Thanks

Comment: After install it, you can take a look for [MSSQLBundle](https://github.com/realestateconz/MssqlBundle)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sql server on my last project.
here is what i've done to make it work on my dev environment

- install pdo-dblib
- composer require leaseweb/doctrine-pdo-dblib
- configure doctrine to use the `driver_class` from the lib above instead of refering the `sql_serv` driver

`driver_class: Lsw\DoctrinePdoDblib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDODblib\Driver`